# How to give the possibility to user to allow HTML caracter in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a form where user will fill data to be push into my database.
Into a field called " description" my user should be able to format the text in HTML for example some Bold, Italic.. etc..
is that possible with TextFormField to give to the user the possiblity to form them selves the text given?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , there are many Packages available on pub.dev , that can easily render Html elements. But after using them , u will be very limited for your text .

One such is : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html.

And if u are going to use Svg also ( not in the text , but anywhere in the app ) , Then use this one : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html

& You can easily store them into your database too